# Is it called a threshold or sill or door frame?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Look at the picture

[image]

What to call the bar at the bottom of the door as shoed in the picture?

> **[threshold](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/threshold?q=threshold)** (n): the floor or ground at the bottom of a doorway, considered as the entrance to a building or room
>
> He stepped across the threshold.
>
> on the threshold She stood hesitating on the threshold.

---

> **[sill](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sill)** /sɪl/ noun [countable]
>
> 1 the narrow shelf at the base of a window frame
>
> 2 the part of a car frame at the bottom of the doors

---

Some people call it a Threshold as in [this picture](https://www.google.com/search?q=door%20anatomy&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=IkU8-ypZ3ZrofM%253A%252CaNKS8r_-q1TviM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRY-JW0YOM_I7vhw2K1gFVBzp2LYg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHyJ_ggavnAhUCUd4KHTNECQUQ_h0wFHoECAwQBg&biw=1229&bih=635#imgrc=IkU8-ypZ3ZrofM:&vet=1)

[image]

Some call it a sill as in [this picture](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1229&bih=635&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=baMyXsuMMMuLr7wPwu--iAY&q=door%20frame&oq=door%20frame&gs_l=img.3..0l10.32344.33656..33866...2.0..0.155.651.6j1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i67.IAIWUM8ajbA&ved=0ahUKEwiL9-fxgqvnAhXLxYsBHcK3D2EQ4dUDCAc&uact=5#imgrc=2URcx52vJLs9lM:)

[image]

For example, when my little daughter touches it, what do I say "**don't touch the threshold / sill / door frame**"?

or **is there any common way to express it?**

Comment: Why would you want someone not to touch the threshold?  (and why do you need to tell her this in English?) Is she allowed to touch the door or the rest of the door frame?  The context seems odd.

Comment: Because it is very dirty. I don't want my toddler get dirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, it is called "**threshold**"

> **[threshold](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/threshold)** [count] 1  : a piece of wood, metal, or stone that forms the
>   bottom of a door and that you walk over as you enter a room or
>   building
>
> He stepped across the threshold.
>
> When they were married he carried her over the threshold. [=he picked
>   her up and carried her into their home when they entered it together
>   for the first time]

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of technical term that builders would know, and most people don't use, especially when talking to toddlers. You would focus more on underlying idea "don't touch dirty things".  Talking to toddlers is fundamentally different to communicating with adult native speakers.  They don't speak English.

> No, Isabel, don't touch that, it's dirty. Let's go play with the crayons. Up you come.

"Threshold" is only commonly used in the expression "crossing the threshold" meaning "make a symbolic first entry into a new place".